# freebsd-update from 8.3-RELEASE to 9.0-RELEASE: How to deal with dozens of diffs?

Tags: freebsd

I am upgrading a FreeBSD 8.3-RELEASE system to FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE using [freebsd-update](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/updating-upgrading-freebsdupdate.html). This is my first time performing a major version upgrade in FreeBSD.

At one point in the process, freebsd-update performs a diff on files which are different then what is expected for the 9.0-RELEASE. It compares the current version on the system with the new changes added from 9.0-RELEASE. I have a modified a couple dozen files under /etc, and I am presented with this diff once per file.

Thus, I am presented with dozens and dozens of diffs which open in a vi window and look like this:

```
The following file could not be merged automatically: /etc/ntp.conf
Press Enter to edit this file in vi and resolve the conflicts
manually...

### vi window opens

<<<<<<< current version
driftfile /etc/ntp/drift
=======
#
# $FreeBSD: release/9.0.0/etc/ntp.conf 195652 2009-07-13 05:51:33Z dwmalone $
#
# Default NTP servers for the FreeBSD operating system.
#
# Don't forget to enable ntpd in /etc/rc.conf with:
# ntpd_enable="YES"
#
# The driftfile is by default /var/db/ntpd.drift, check
# /etc/defaults/rc.conf on how to change the location.
#
>>>>>>> 9.0-RELEASE

restrict default notrust nomodify ignore
```

And it complains about minor version numbers:

```
--- current version
+++ new version
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
-# $FreeBSD: src/gnu/usr.bin/man/manpath/manpath.config,v 1.25.28.1 2009/04/15 03:14:26 kensmith Exp $
+# $FreeBSD: src/gnu/usr.bin/man/manpath/manpath.config,v 1.25.32.1 2010/12/21 17:10:29 kensmith Exp $
 #
 # This file is read by manpath(1) to configure the mandatory manpath,
 # optional manpath and to map each path element to a manpath element.
 # The format is:
 #
Does this look reasonable (y/n)? y
```

And fact it complains about the RCS version string on dozens of files:

```
--- current version
+++ new version
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-# $FreeBSD: src/etc/amd.map,v 1.10.8.1 2009/04/15 03:14:26 kensmith Exp $
+# $FreeBSD: release/9.0.0/etc/amd.map 164015 2006-11-06 01:42:11Z obrien $
 #
 /defaults       type:=host;fs:=${autodir}/${rhost}/host;rhost:=${key}
 *               opts:=rw,grpid,resvport,vers=3,proto=tcp,nosuid,nodev
Does this look reasonable (y/n)?
```

And even complains because I removed the FreeBSD version number from my local (custom) `/etc/passwd` file:

```
<<<<<<< current version
=======
# $FreeBSD: release/8.4.0/etc/master.passwd 243948 2012-12-06 11:54:25Z rwatson $
#
>>>>>>> 8.4-RELEASE
root:*:0:0:Charlie &:/root:/bin/csh
toor:*:0:0:Bourne-again Superuser:/root:
daemon:*:1:1:Owner of many system processes:/root:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

And so on.

This requires that I manually edit each file and remove the strings like `<<<<<<< current version` `>>>>>>> 9.0-RELEASE` and `=======`, and manually merge these files. As I discovered afterwards, if I don't remove these strings, they end up in the file afterwards. There are dozens of files which differ between 8.3 and 9.0, and I have a dozen local modifications myself.

It appears that `freebsd-update` is using a diff, sdiff or [mergemaster function](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mergemaster&sektion=8) of some sort, but I can't tell what it is doing exactly.

Processing these files is tedious. Is there a way that I can just say "Accept new version" or "keep old version" or "Your merge is correct"? There has got to be an easier way to deal with these files. I must be missing something.

This isn't a huge problem for one machine, but eventually I'll be doing this dozens of times and I want to find an easier way.

And I am not alone. At least one other admin out there has pointed out this problem. The author of [Zytrax.com: FreeBSD Update Survival Guide: freebsd-update upgrading minor or major versions](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/survival/freebsd-update.html#upgrading) also talks about this situation:

> **Notes:**
>
> 1. When updating to a new release lots of stuff changes (much less so with a minor release). When scripts and configurations files are
>      modified freebsd-update diffs them, loads them into vi and presents
>      them for reconciliation. Since most of the changes are simple version
>      number comment field changes this can be a serious pain (in our case
>      well over 50 files were changed, over 40 were comment only changes).
>      However, be warned - diligence is necessary (no :wq to every file
>      without looking). Further, unless the file is visibly short all the
>      diff marks (:/>>>/) need to be viewed and reconciled. Failure to do
>      this will cause the resulting file to contain the diff indicators and
>      many essential system files will simply croak when loaded (including
>      the password file in our case) resulting in endless hours of fun
>      looking for the files that were modified (guess how we found this
>      out). While there is really no alternative to genuine file changes,
>      having to undergo the edit reconciliation for comment only changes
>      results in a serious shortcoming in the process. Better, perhaps, to
>      move the replaced files into a special location and let the user
>      manually reconcile those of interest. Just how often do you change
>      /etc/periodic/weekly/310.locate?

Update:

Looks like these diffs are managed by [merge(1)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=merge&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%209.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html), not mergemaster. From the merge(1) manpage:

```
   A conflict occurs if both file1 and file3 have changes in a common seg-
   ment of lines.  If a conflict is found, merge normally outputs a  warn-
   ing  and brackets the conflict with <<<<<<< and >>>>>>> lines.  A typi-
   cal conflict will look like this:

      <<<<<<< file A
      lines in file A
      =======
      lines in file B
      >>>>>>> file B
```

Comment: I've done several version upgrades using freebsd-update, and not had this issue. I just tried an 8.3 to 9.0 upgrade, and the number of files that required any manual merging was zero. I don't know what might cause your symptoms.

Comment: @hmallett : These are files which we have modified locally.

Comment: Really? You've never updated files like `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/resolv.conf`? That is where I am seeing this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't getting much response here, so I asked at [forums.freebsd.org](https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?&t=33166).

The short answer is: No. There is no easy way to merge these changes using freebsd-update. freebsd-update uses [merge(1)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=merge&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%209.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) to perform the diffs and merging, and `merge` is not very friendly or flexible.

There are other options, such as  sysutils/etcupdate as suggested by kworr. However, I don't see how that can be integrated with freebsd-update.

From what I read, freebsd-update is a convenient way to upgrade FreeBSD, but it fails in other ways. Many FreeBSD admins don't use freebsd-update at all, and prefer the manual way using using the source and [mergemaster(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mergemaster&sektion=8).

Comment: can you fix forum link please? i'd like to read/join)

Comment: I updated the link for you. https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?&t=33166

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that in many cases, the older way will give less trouble; that is, if you're upgrading from a non-RELEASE "branch", major version upgrades, etc.

But freebsd-update is "da schiz" for keeping a RELEASE-branch system current with security patches (or, in other words, a production machine/server).

*Anytime* you update from something more than a few months old there are likely some changes to files in /etc --- the older way uses "mergemaster", which is *slightly* more friendly that merge, but updating merges to /etc/ files that have been modified is always going to be a PITA that requires a good bit of manual intervention.  It's just that mergemaster is a tad (only a tad) more "user-friendly".

Answer (score 0):

There's a good thing named [sysutils/etcupdate](http://www.freshports.org/sysutils/etcupdate) in the ports. It can do a semi-auto three-way merge of your configs requiring minimal involvment.

Comment: kworr, are you suggesting that I don't use freebsd-update? How would I use etcupdate with freebsd-update?

Comment: You don't need to ditch freebsd-update, just make sure you tell it not to MergeChanges. I have no experience with freebsd-update so you better test this update path on any other machine.

Answer (score 0):

From my reading of the handbook, you can set some of this behavior in the configuration file for freebsd-update:

```
    # Paths which start with anything matching an entry in an UpdateIfUnmodified
    # statement will only be updated if the contents of the file have not been
    # modified by the user (unless changes are merged; see below).
      UpdateIfUnmodified /etc/ /var/ /root/ /.cshrc /.profile
```

While I've always done updates/upgrades the manual way, I might try this on my test machine to see how it goes.

Comment: My systems do have that setting (I think it's a default). The trouble is, the files are slightly modified and FreeBSD forces a diff for those (The $ID$ tag is different between 8 -> 9, the root password is set, etc.). It's a known problem that FreeBSD never fixed. Now that we're on FreeBSD 9, this may not be an issue upgrading to 10 if we decide to stay with FreeBSD.